# Raspberry pi direct connect over ethernet

Tags: ssh, ethernet

**Simplified**:

I been wondering on how to connect my Macbook and Raspberry Pi together over **ethernet** ( I do not have access to a crossover atm). I've set up, on the Pi side, by typing

```
sudo ip add *insert Pi ip here*/24 dev eth0
```

but when I attempt to use this exact line (changed ip), Macbook doen't connect. At all. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I will suggest to ask this question on a MAC blog. 
From Rasbian is easy. 
Just make sure you have the SSH option enabled on your raspi-config -> Advanced Options.

Comment: Crossover Ethernet cables have not been needed for decades.

Comment: If you want an easy way to connect directly to the pi, and you got a usb-serial converter, you can just connect tx and rx on the pi GPIO14 and GPIO15, and usb to mac, than make a serial connection. like screen, or something

Comment: The following instructables helped me achieve this task using a standard Ethernet cable ... http://www.instructables.com/id/Configuring-the-Raspberry-Pi-ethernet-port-for-rem/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: @Kolban Doing that on recent (post May) Raspbian will break things.

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of Raspbian (which use `dhcpcd`) allow ssh to work over a link-local address and `avahai` (which is a zeroconf implementation) enables programs to discover hosts running on a local network.

This means you can plug the Pi into a Computer (with an Ethernet cable) or a local network router and connect without knowing the IP address.

You can easily connect from OS X with `ssh pi@hostname.local` (the default hostname is raspberrypi)

You can use a crossover cable, but you don't need one (most modern interfaces automatically detect).

I think this answers the question I think you are asking. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip/37921#37921) if you want more detail.